# Show that T is a rotation through an angle, and find the angle

Tags: linear-algebra

$T\left[\begin{array}{c}x \\ y \end{array}\right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\begin{array}{c}x+y \\ -x+y \end{array}\right]$

This is my attempt, but I'm stuck. Can someone continue?

$T\left[\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} \cos θ & -\sin θ \\ \sin θ & \cos θ \end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{c}x \\ y \end{array}\right]$

$= \left[\begin{array}{c} x\cos θ - y\sin θ \\ x\sin θ + y\cos θ \end{array}\right]$

Comment: Your matrix multiplication isn't correct - try that one again. It produces a vector (it would be weird for a vector transformation to turn a vector into a matrix, no?)

Comment: I was just about to correct the dot product, if that's what you're talking about.

Comment: Is it correct now? I can tell it's starting to look like what the desired answer is.

Comment: Spot on. Now you can insist upon what theta must be in order to show the original statement.

Comment: Please, please don't call that a dot product. That's just a dumbed down phrase for an inner product, which this isn't.

Comment: Sorry, I actually don't know what to do next. I did have the correct matrix multiplication on paper, and this is where I've been stuck.

Comment: Well you know that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} x + y \\ -x + y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x\cos\theta - y\sin\theta \\ x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta \end{pmatrix}$$ - so equate each line. $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (x + y) = x\cos\theta - y\sin\theta$$ - so you know $\cos\theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$  and $\sin\theta = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ - as pointed out below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find a rotation matrix that has the same effect as the matrix you have. You can then easily find the angle of rotation. We can write it like this to make it clearer (I've just re-written your first equation as a 
matrix product rather than the way you have it):

$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\theta & -\sin \theta  \\
\sin\theta & \cos \theta   \end{array} \right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
\end{array}
\right)= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{array} \right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

so you can see we need to find the angle $\theta$ such that:

$$ \cos\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \;\;\text{  and  } \;\; -\sin\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\sin\theta=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \;\;\text{  and  } \;\; \cos\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
which is a consistent set of equations with a solution: $$\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
So we can then interpret it as a rotation by an angle of $\pi/4$ radians or $45^\circ$.

---

Hopefully this makes it a little clearer how I got the right hand side of the first equation:
$$ T \left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
\end{array}
\right) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
x+y\\
-x+y\\
\end{array}
\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1  \\
-1 & 1   \end{array} \right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
\end{array}
\right)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{array} \right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: I don't get how you did this line. $$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos\theta & -\sin \theta  \\
\sin\theta & \cos \theta   \end{array} \right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
\end{array}
\right)= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} &\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{array} \right) \left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: It's intuition. Jay kind of skipped a step for you there - but if you multiply that matrix by your vector, you'll see it does the right thing.

Comment: @fossdeep I've added the steps I skipped to get the right-hand side of the equation, hopefully it makes it a little clearer

Comment: I get it now. That's great. Thanks.

Comment: @fossdeep no worries, glad to help!